# Does joomla updates by itself?

Tags: update

I'd like that my site, which uses joomla 3.4.5, automaticly be updated by itself.
Wordpress has this with the option `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'true' );` in the file wp-config.php.
If it is possible, how can i do it?
I'm not a webdevelopper but i can manage to make configurations.
Thanks.

Comment: If you do decide to use any of the suggestions for Auto Update provided in the answers I would suggest you manually update Joomla and your Extensions to their current levels before you implement Auto Update. Joomla 3.4.x is relatively old and there have been a lot of changes and improvements over the years.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic Joomla core updates will likely work better on websites with few or no third party extensions and/or on websites where third party extensions are also being regularly updated.

If automating Joomla core updates, you should probably also automate backups (e.g. by installing Akeeba Backup and enabling the "System - Backup on update" plugin) in case of a bad update so you can restore if needed.

**watchful.net**

As [FFrewin](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/126/ffrewin) points out automatic Joomla core updates are a feature of watchful.net.

**Softaculous**

Automatic Joomla core updates can be enabled in some hosting control panel applications such as Softaculous.

**Joomla Extensions**

The free [Auto Update for Joomla](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/auto-update-for-joomla) extension automatically keeps Joomla 3.x websites up to date using a cron job.

**Akeeba Panopticon**

This was not available when the question was first asked but Akeeba Panopticon can automate Joomla Core updates.

Comment: That's a good point - I think this is a feature that hosting control panels provide when you install a web-application from within their application installer. Then they have the ability to auto-update the web application when there is a new update.

Answer (score 1):

There is no auto-update in Joomla. And actually autoupdate can be a [bad idea.](https://brian.teeman.net/joomla/835-automatic-updates-for-joomla-are-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 1):

Although there is some discussion in Joomla for this feature for some time now, currently there is no such feature available. I can't say if it's a good or bad idea, as this can be a long discussion.

There is a back-end notification system though, for Joomla core and any compatible extensions that use the Joomla updater.

I think that if you install Akeeba CMS update, it might have a feature to send you also email notifications.

Finally [**Watchful.li**](https://watchful.li) is a 3rd party Service, that can help with the monitoring, administration and updates of your Joomla sites, from 1 single point.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-updating is dangerous. In fact, I find it weird that most WordPress websites auto-update themselves with no problem whatsoever. In Joomla, the possibility of problems is much higher, considering the limited number of volunteers to test each and every extension for the current update, and the number of extensions that people have that are no longer supported.

I am not saying that this is not feasible in Joomla, it is, but it requires a lot of technical knowledge with the system in order to do it, and again, it won't be safe.

Officially, this has been discussed several times. Here is one of the threads about this from 8 years ago: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/11937